# How do I let my function inside of a class see what a string allocates?

Tags: c++

I know that this would be a nightmare code to read for us, but I am struggling with classes and trying to become better.

I get this error:

```
main.cpp:38:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nemesis'
    if (nemesis == "p") {
```

Obviously, it is not a good code and yes, I can code it a lot better, but how can I let the code access `nemesis` from `main()`?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Calculator {
    public:
        void NumberSet(double input, double input2);
        double Multiplication(double value, double secondvalue);
        double Division(double valie, double secondvalue);
        double Simple(double value, double secondvalue);
        void PlusorMinus(string name);
        void Word(string name);
    private:
        double num;
        double num2;
};

void Calculator::NumberSet(double input, double input2) {
    this->num = input;
    this->num2 = input2;
}

double Calculator::Multiplication(double value, double secondvalue) {
    return value * secondvalue;
}

double Calculator::Division(double valie, double secondvalue) {
    return valie / secondvalue;
}

void Calculator::Word(string name) {
    string nemesis = name;
}

double Calculator::Simple(double value, double secondvalue) {
    if (nemesis == "p") {
        return value + secondvalue;
    }
    else {
        return value - secondvalue;
    }
}

int main() {
    string punyword;
    string nemesis;
    int num1;
    int num2;
    Calculator calculator;

    cout << "Would you like to use this complex complicator, puny human? Type yes or no" << endl;
    cin >> punyword;
    if (punyword == "yes") {
        cout << "Multiplication? type M and 2 numers like that M 2 3, similar things can be performed for division, sum, substraction!!! " << endl;
        cin >> nemesis, num1, num2;
        calculator.Word(nemesis);

        if (nemesis == "M") {
            cout << calculator.Multiplication(num1,num2) << endl;
        }
        else if (nemesis == "D") {
            cout << calculator.Division(num1,num2) << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << calculator.Simple(num1,num2) << endl;
        }  
    }
    else {
        cout << "very funny" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This has nothing to do with classes, nor what the string "allocates". It has everything to do with variable scope. In `Calculator::Word`, `nemesis` is a **local** variable, just like it would be if you had written `void myfunc() { string nemesis; }` and then tried to use `nemesis` from `main`. I think you should try to follow a c++ tutorial and make sure you understand the fundamentals, **in order**. Don't try to learn classes until you properly understand functions.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `nemesis` inside of the `Calculator::Word()` method to be a member of the `Calculator` class itself, eg:

```
class Calculator {
    public:
        ...
        double Simple(double value, double secondvalue);
        ...
        void Word(string name);
    private:
        string nemesis;. // <-- move it here
        ...
};

void Calculator::Word(string name) {
    nemesis = name;
}

double Calculator::Simple(double value, double secondvalue) {
    if (nemesis == "p") {
        return value + secondvalue;
    }
    else {
        return value - secondvalue;
    }
}
```